# click on button and wait for network response in puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer, browser-automation

I am trying to click on a button in the loop to load data from server.
on each click, button makes a network request to the server and then display data fetched from server.

what I want to do is wait for response from server before making next click/before next ietration. this is what I have done so far.

```
let count = 0;
while (true) {
    try {
      /**
       * click then wait for a response.
       */
      await page.waitForSelector(".loadmoredata");

      await page.click(".loadmoredata");
      console.log("clicked", count);
      // logic to wait for a response but it's not working
      const response = await page.waitForResponse((response) => {
        if (response.status() !== 200) return false;
        return true;
      });
      if (!response) {
        page.waitForTimeout(5000);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      if (error instanceof errors.TimeoutError) {
        break;
      }
    }
    count++;
  }
```

when I run the code whenever the response is a bit late loop continues in iteration and doesn't wait for response.
expected output:
clicked 0

clicked 1

clicked 2

clicked 3

clicked 4

see the real output:
[image]

these extra iterations are because it doesn't wait for a response. I have searched on the internet and tried to get solution from API documentation of puppeteer but nothing helped me to solve this problem.

Comment: You need to `await page.waitForTimeout(5000);` if you _must_ use a sleep (although I imagine the `waitForResponse` will throw, skipping that code anyway). Also, pages typically send tons of requests, so if you're not filtering by URL, you might want to do that, just to make sure you're not sniffing the wrong response. As with all Puppeteer questions, it's generally difficult to help without being able to run the code on the actual site, since websites have highly complex, arbitrary behavior that is important to see.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question) also applies. No reason the output shouldn't be a text code block.

Comment: Thank u @ggorlen for your response. You're right that's what I did. I opened the network tab and simulate all request on slow 3G network, each request was taking less than 3 seconds. So instead of using `waitForResponse` as you mentioned I used waitForTimeout(4000) and it actually worked.

Comment: That might appear to work, but [`waitForTimeout(4000)` is generally a poor solution](https://serpapi.com/blog/puppeteer-antipatterns/#overusing-waitfortimeout) that causes a race condition and bypasses the event-driven design of Puppeteer. So if you provide the website others can give you a more robust solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: "networkidle2" });
```